# Firefox not reflecting CSS Transforms and perspective

Tags: css, css-transforms, perspective

I have a navigation I'm working on that I want the links to be skewed inwards about 40deg. I have it working fine in chrome, but am seeing some issues with hovering, selecting, and positioning in FF, Safari and IE.

From doing my own debugging, i've come down to I think this line is messing it up outside of chrome:

```
.splash-content {
    transform-origin: center right; //this line
}
```

, however, that is being uses to align the navigation and can't be removed. So now I'm very confused on what could be happening/causing. I'm really only doing a small rotate and couldn't imagine browsers not supporting something this basic.

Are there any alternatives that could help me accomplish this so the experience isn't terrible in other browsers? Attached is my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7te51zw0/

---

Minimal Example (More fleshed out/styled version in JSFiddle)

HTML

```
<div class="splash-perspective">
  <div class="splash-outer-container">
    <div class="splash-stage">
      <ul class="splash-menu">
        <li class="splash-menu__item">
          <div class="splash-content">
            <a href="#">Shop</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* SPLASH MENU */
.splash-perspective {
  perspective: 100vw;
}

.splash-container {
  transform: translateZ(0);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.splash-stage {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.splash-menu {
  text-align: right;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.splash-menu__item {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.splash-content {
  transform: rotateY(-60deg) translateZ(0) scale(1);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: center right;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.splash-content:hover {
  background: red;
  transform: rotateY(-25deg) translateZ(0) scale(1);
  cursor: pointer;

}
```

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, within your question, and not any third party site.

Comment: @Rob I'll update, but i've been on this site for years and have never once had an issue with providing a jsfiddle, as opposed to filling the question with a ton of code.

Comment: With 8000 to 10,000 visitors every day, we're typing as fast we can to close such questions. Unfortunately, newer people with the ability to close such things have given up trying to maintain the rules (which I link to). I help close up to 40 such things every day so sometimes it just takes a while. In any case, don't jump off a cliff when everybody else does.

Comment: Updated with example

Comment: The problem is that your links are now below their container, which does catch all the pointer events. You could quick-hack it by [disabling the pointer-events on the container](https://jsfiddle.net/y1vz0e49/1/), but you might be better rotating the whole container instead of each item individually.

Comment: Ps: [here is a **minimal** reproducible example](https://jsfiddle.net/6cbz2w4m/)

Comment: @kaiido, that wouldn't allow me to remove the translate on each item though, would it?

Comment: @Kaiido, I switched to that, but I am still having unclickable links in firefox. I think it's related to `transform-origin: center right;` but I can't seem to find a fix`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```css
.splash-content:hover {
  background: red;
  transform: rotateY(-25deg) translateZ(0) scale(1);
  cursor: pointer;

}

/* change above css to below */

.splash-menu__item:hover .splash-content {
  background: red;
  transform: rotateY(-25deg) translateZ(0) scale(1);
  cursor: pointer;

}
```